# Using MPICH on two differnt architectures

Tags: raspberry-pi, mpi, slackware

I am new to MPI. I am trying to get my x86 laptop and and a raspberry pi to "work together" via mpi. However I am having a hard time setting it up for the two to work together. I made a machinefile to store IP addresses. When I am running on the raspberry pi with only its IP in the machine file everything runs as expected, it is the same with the laptop. However when I have both IPs in the machine file nothing happens, I have to use ctrl+c to kill the command. On the laptop I am running slackware and on the raspberry pi raspbian.

Here is what I get when i run mpiexec --version

```html
# raspberry pi###############
HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 3.4.1
    Release Date:                            Fri Jan 22 14:17:48 CST 2021
    CC:                              gcc -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/mpich-a7gXGS/mpich-3.4.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Wl,-z,relro
    Configure options:                       '--with-hwloc-prefix=/usr' '--with-device=ch3' 'FFLAGS=-O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/mpich-a7gXGS/mpich-3.4.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -fallow-invalid-boz -fallow-argument-mismatch' '--prefix=/usr' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/mpich-a7gXGS/mpich-3.4.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:
    Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
    Demux engines available:                 poll select
    

# Slackware
mpiexec (OpenRTE) 4.1.0

Report bugs to http://www.open-mpi.org/community/help/
```

the command I am running, on slackware, is

> mpirun --hostfile machinefile -np 2 hostname

I want the laptop to be like a head for multiple raspberrys. I Imagined that since mpi is a standard I would be able to get these two versions to communicate without much of a hassle. Is there something I need to configure to get these two computers to work?

Thanks for your time

Comment: you are running MPICH on your rpi and Open MPI on your laptop. They do not interoperate so you should at the very least use the same library (vendor and version) on both systems.

Comment: thanks, I'll uninstall MPICH on the pi and install OpenMPI. I thought I installed MPICH on both. Seeing that on slackware I installed the package mpich-3.4.3. but looking at at my other packages I see that kicad installed openmpi. thanks for your help

Comment: ok both are giving me the same output when i run mpiexec --version. But it still hangs when I run mpirun --hostfile machinefile -np 2 hostname. even when I have np 1.

Comment: if you are running any firewall on or between your machines, try disabling all of them.